# How to retrieve a stolen Yahoo account's password?

Tags: password-recovery, yahoo

One of my friends just got hacked on her PC and her Yahoo account password was stolen. Now the hacker use her account under her name for bad reason. He may have change alternative email, security question, etc.

What can we do about that? We need her account back. Is it possible?

ps. I tried to google search for Yahoo contact information but I'm not sure where to knock Yahoo door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://pctechnotes.com/how-to-recover-your-hacked-yahoo-account/):

**How to recover your Hacked Yahoo! Account:**

> “To be able to reset your hacked yahoo
>   password just send a mail to Yahoo
>   Security Department –
>   account-security-help@cc.yahoo-inc.com.
>   always remember to be polite in
>   contacting them, tell the whole story,
>   don’t blame them for your hacked
>   account, tell them when is the last
>   time you access your account, supply
>   them the password that you last used
>   to accessed your account, give them
>   all the information you entered when
>   you register your account or just the
>   information when you last update your
>   account.”

Answer (score 1):

If you're locked out, you're locked out. Yahoo likely won't care unless you're a paying customer. Basically, if you don't have access to the alternate email on file then you really have no chance.
This is the details from their page:

> You can get a new password, a Yahoo! ID reminder, or both. If you forgot
>   your Yahoo! ID or password, go to the
>   [Sign-in Problems page](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot/).
>
> If you forgot your Yahoo! ID, you need
>   to provide three pieces of information
>   so we can confirm your identity:
>
> ```
> Your birthday
> Your ZIP or postal code (at the time you created your Yahoo! account
> ```
>
> or when you last updated it)
>       Your alternate email address -Note: You must have access to this email address
>       Country code (at the time you created your Yahoo! account or when
>   you last updated it)
>
> Be sure to provide the same
>   information you gave the last time you
>   registered for a new Yahoo! ID or
>   password or the last time you updated
>   your account.
>
> If you forgot your password, you can
>   create a new one. But first you’ll
>   have to provide the following
>   information so we can confirm your
>   identity:
>
> ```
> Your Yahoo! ID
> Alternate email address, mobile phone number, or the answers to your
> ```
>
> secret questions
>
> A Reset Your Password link will be
>   sent to your alternate email address.
>   Click the link and enter your new
>   password in the Reset your password
>   page.
>
> If you entered your secret question
>   incorrectly or forgot what you
>   originally entered, for security
>   reasons, we cannot tell you what your
>   Yahoo! ID is or let you create a new
>   password.